# Same document is printing differently to 2 different printers

Tags: printing

I have software that generates PDFs and sends them to print via the `lp` program. The same PDF prints slightly different to 2 different printers. The font and margins are different.

How can I standardize the margins and font between the two printers? Is this just a difference in the drivers for each printer?

Before you suggest it, the `page-top` etc options do not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

All printers have their default settings and no two printers print exactly the same.  If you want them to print the document out exactly I would start by looking at each of the printers Margin settings.

Comment: How can I modify a printer's margin settings from the command line?

Comment: to set margins on command line, use `lp -o page-left=value -o page-right=value -o page-top=value -o page-bottom=value filename` where value is in points (1/72")